# Using Maclaurin expansion to find approximation for an equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion

So I wonder how can I use Maclaurin expansion to get an approx answer for this equation:

$ 10x^2 = \cos(x)$

The error must be no bigger than $10^{-4}$

I know that I need to use Lagrange error bound. But I have no idea how to implement this idea here.

I started with writing Maclaurin expansion of order 3 for $\cos(x)$:

$\cos(x)$ = $ 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + R_3(x)$

Where $R_3(x)$ is the remainder.

$ 10x^2 = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + R_3(x)$

But from here I have no idea what to do, I don't think that's even the right approach to this problem.

Can someone explain to me how can I use Maclaurin expansion to find an approx answer to equations?

Thank you.

Comment: There's an explicit form for $R$ which can be very helpful..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we may use the Maclaurin expansion but we need an explicit form for the remainder. By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder),
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+R_4(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{\cos(t)x^4}{4!}$$
where $0<t<x$.
Let $x_0$ be the positive solution of $10x^2 = \cos(x)$ and let 
$x_1$ be the positive solution of the approximate equation $10x^2 = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ i.e. $x_1=\sqrt{2/21}\approx 0.3086067$. 
Note that $f(x)=10x^2-\cos(x)$ is an even continuous function which is increasing for $x\geq 0$. Since $f(0.3)<0$, $f(0.31)>0$ it follows that $x_0\in(0.3,0.31)$.

Now we try to bound the distance $|x_0-x_1|$. 
We have that $$\frac{21x_0^2}{2}=1+\frac{\cos(t)x_0^4}{4!}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{21x_1^2}{2}=1$$ and therefore
$$0<x_0^2-x_1^2=\frac{\cos(t)x_0^4}{252}$$ 
or
$$0<x_0-x_1=\frac{\cos(t)x_0^4}{252 (x_0+x_1)}< \frac{x_0^4}{504\sqrt{2/21}}<10^{-4}.$$
where at the last step we used the rough estimate $x_0\in (0.3,0.31)$.

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Sooner or later, you will learn that, for function approximation, [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) are much better than Taylor expansions (if, on this you type *Padé* in the search bar, you will find hundreds of entries).

Developed around $x=0$, the $[n,m]$ approximant write

$$f(x)=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\,x^i }{1+\sum_{i=1}^m b_i\,x^i  }$$ and, as for Taylor, the coefficients are related to the derivatives of the function at $x=0$.

To make your problem simple, let $t=x^2$ and work the $[1,n]$ approximant. This means that the approximation of the solution is obtained solving a linear equation in $x$.

Applied to your case, the successive approximants will be
$$P_0=\frac{21 t}{2}-1\qquad P_1=\frac{\frac{2645 t}{252}-1}{\frac{t}{252}+1}\qquad P_2=\frac{\frac{832861 t}{79350}-1}{-\frac{37 t^2}{317400}+\frac{157 t}{39675}+1}$$ and so on.

In the table, I give you, as a function of $n$, the rational value of the approximate solution $t_n=x_n^2$ as well as its decimal representation.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & t_n & t_n \approx \\
 0 & \frac{2}{21} &   0.0952380952380952 \\
 1 & \frac{252}{2645} &  0.0952741020793951 \\
 2 & \frac{79350}{832861} &  0.0952740013039391 \\
 3 & \frac{46640216}{489537705} &   0.0952740014173168 \\
 4 & \frac{44058393450}{462438784921} &   0.0952740014173479 \\
 5 & \frac{61041919609572}{640698602992205} &   0.0952740014173477 \\
 6 &\frac{116607145744581310}{1223913596677690101} & 0.0952740014173477
\end{array}
\right)$$